# iostream file not found error when compiling a precompile header in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, pch

I get a `'iostream' file not found` error when compiling my `Prefix.pch` precompile header file in Xcode 9.  It seems the compiler can't find it, yet it finds `<stdio.h>` and `<Foundation/Foundation.h>` files just fine.

```
#include <stdio.h> // ok
#include <iostream> // error
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h> // ok
```

[EDIT]
The project is a mix of C++ and Objective-C files, and I am trying to pull into the `.pch` file some header files that are C++.  I am unable to figure out how to mix the two in the `.pch` file.

Comment: Are you building a C++ source file? Or a C source file? Can you please copy the complete and full output (as text) and paste it into the question? It should include the file-name which should give us (and you!) some hint about that.

Comment: This is a precompile header file, a `.pch` file.

Comment: You still need to copy-paste the full and complete output.

Comment: Actually, that `#import` thing could give a hint: It's part of Objective-C (or Objective-C++). My ***guess*** is that you're building an Objective-**C** project, not Objective-C++.

Comment: I don't have text output of compilation.  I am compiling in Xcode.  I have output displayed in the issue navigator.  The error is: `'iosstream' file not found` in Prefix.pch

Comment: Possible duplicate of [iostream.h, fstream.h cannot be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225277/iostream-h-fstream-h-cannot-be-found)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should modify the pch with `#ifdef` preprocessor directives:

```cpp
#ifdef __cplusplus
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>
#endif

#ifdef __OBJC__
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#enid
```

(I just ran into this problem and solved it in this way.)